# Is it possible to update/remove/install 1 package with composer without updating everything?

Tags: drush, composer

I have seen a few posts answering this and saying that "composer require package" or "composer update package" will do this; but absolutely everything i do with composer attempts to update everything listed in require section of composer.json.

I thought perhaps just removing the require lines in composer.json would avoid this mess; but composer then removes these modules from my docroot.

I simply want to remove my broken (not sure why) version of drush on the server and replace it with a new one without updating core or any contrib modules.

composer remove drush/drush - but it fails the removal and then tries to update everything

> xxx:~/www/d8$ composer remove drush/drush drush/drush is not required
>   in your composer.json and has not been removed
>
> > DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion Package "drush/drush" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring. Loading
> >     composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies
> >     (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an
> >     installable set of packages.

any composer command i try (rmeove, update, require) seems to want to update everything.. and then fails because of dependencies conflicts (which is good; since I don't want anything being updated anyway).

## composer.json

```
{
    "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.8",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
        "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
        "drupal/address": "^1.7",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.27",
        "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/backup_migrate": "^4.0",
        "drupal/block_class": "^1.0",
        "drupal/clientside_validation": "^1.2",
        "drupal/coffee": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/commerce": "2.17",
        "drupal/conditional_fields": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
        "drupal/content_access": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/core": "^8.7.0",
        "drupal/csv_serialization": "^1.4",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.2",
        "drupal/date_popup": "^1.0",
        "drupal/date_popup_timepicker": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.7",
        "drupal/external_links_new_tab": "^1.2",
        "drupal/extlink": "^1.1",
        "drupal/field_group": "^1.0",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.0@RC",
        "drupal/filefield_paths": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/fillpdf": "4.x-dev",
        "drupal/viewsreference": "^1.4",
        "drush/drush": "^10.2",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
        "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.7.0"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patchLevel": {
            "drupal/core": "-p2"
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        },
        "patches": {
            "drupal/core": {
                "Drag-drop fix for field group config": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-12-09/drupal-tabledrag_testing-2769825-48.patch",
                "part of above": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-11-21/3062742_4.patch",
                "multiple terms in views issues": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-11-14/drupal-empty_value_fix-2882076-14.patch",
                "more drag-drop fixes": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-12-14/3089151-17-D8.patch"
            },
            "drupal/conditional_fields": {
                "Date field value is always empty": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-01-19/conditional_fields-date_fields_empty-2956612-8.patch"
            },
            "drupal/fillpdf": {
                "Add token support for before/after text": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-18/3109697-6.patch"
            },
            "drupal/field_group": {
                "Conditional field support": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-12-10/field_group-support_conditional_fields-3099051-6.patch",
                "HTML5 validation broken in tabs": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-10-04/field_group-HTML5_validation_prevents_submission_in_tabs-2969051-9.patch"
            },
            "drupal/serial": {
                "Feeds support": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-28/serial-feeds-support-3035978-6.patch"
            }
        },
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "initial": {
                ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
                ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds really odd. Can you please add your current composer.json to your question and name your composer --version please?

Comment: What does `composer remove drush/drush --no-update` do?

Comment: adding --no-update means the only thing done is to add/remove the line from the composer.json.. it doesn't actually do anything else. Based on if that line has been added or removed (i suspect same to just remove it manually), when composer update or any action without --no-update, it will then be removed or added.. and sadly, everything else will be updated.

Comment: Maybe composer.lock or the vendor folder is missing, and any operation would mean Composer needs to install what it thinks is missing (invoking the dependency check)?

Comment: No. These are all in place. Perhaps my question is worded wrong? I should have maybe started with "How do you install/remove/update a composer package without updating everything?"

Comment: Any solution on this? It seems that it should be possible to require a new module without making any other changes. This is needed for cases such as testing a module out, so there must (or should) be a switch of some kind to prevent it from going commando on your currently working site.

Comment: @Jav.. to be honest; since i posted this i have gained much more experience working with composer. It all works as it should. If the composer.json is not tying each package to a specific version it will attempt to update as specified. I believe though that will only occur if you wipe out the .lock file or run composer update. i regularly install new packages or update specific ones now without fear of updating something that wasn't intended. I never remove the lock file; but if i were to do that.. i make sure anything which needs a specific version is listed in .json that way.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is `composer require package/name`, `composer remove package/name`, or `composer update package/name`. Version number is optional. You are doing it correctly.

The line about "Updating dependencies" is expected. It is not updating the versions of your packages (unless required by the require/remove statement), it's updating dependency information based on your require/remove/update.

Comment: No. Its updating everything that has a newer version.

Comment: If you have a `composer.lock` file and you are doing a `composer require package/name` then it will not update everything. If your `vendor/` directory does not match what is in the `composer.lock` file composer will update (or downgrade) packages in the vendor folder to match what is in the lock file. If you are seeing packages update with a`composer require` then something else is going on, or you are misinterpreting the output you are seeing. `composer require` does not do an update on all available packages. My assumption here is misinterpretation of the output.